# How to link a Jupyter Slider-Widget to a VTK object in live view

Tags: python, widget, vtk

I would like to move a slider and thus affect the Z-coordinate of a 3D-Point, which is part of a line. This line then I want to visualize in a jupyter notebook via a view - widget found in the itkwidgets library.

What I came up so far looks like this, but no matter what I do, the object in view-widget is the same.

```
import numpy as np
import vtk

from ipywidgets import widgets, interactive
from itkwidgets import view


def moveZ(zVal=0.2):
    rail_points.SetPoint(0, (x_res[0],y_res[0],zVal))
    rail.SetPoints(rail_points)
    rail.Update()
    tube.Update()
    mappers[0].Update()


rail = vtk.vtkLineSource()

rail_points = vtk.vtkPoints()
for _x, _y, _z in zip(x_res, y_res, np.linspace(1,0,len(x_res))):
    rail_points.InsertNextPoint(np.array([_x,_y,_z],dtype='float32'))

rail.SetPoints(rail_points)
rail.SetPoint1([0,0,0])
rail.SetPoint2([0,0,0])

tube = vtk.vtkTubeFilter()
tube.SetInputConnection(rail.GetOutputPort())
tube.SetVaryRadiusToVaryRadiusOff()
tube.SetRadius(0.1)

geometricObjectSources=[]

geometricObjectSources.append(tube)

mappers = []
actors = []

for i in range(len(geometricObjectSources)):
    geometricObjectSources[i].Update()

    mappers.append(vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper())
    mappers[i].SetInputConnection(geometricObjectSources[i].GetOutputPort())

    actors.append(vtk.vtkActor())
    actors[i].SetMapper(mappers[i])


viewer = view(actors=actors)

slider = interactive(moveZ, zVal=(-1, 1, 0.1))

widgets.VBox([viewer, slider])
```

Also, I tried changing other properties via the slider, such as the tube radius, the position of a sphere, with no success so far. Somehow I have the feeling that the view-window is not really updating once the objects update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code, but I think what you need to do is
attach a so-called "observer" callback to a slider which changes
the parameter you want it to change.  Here is a screenshot of with
a slider which changes the height of a triangle in a diagram widget:
[image]
Here is the pasteable code which sets up the diagram

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from jp_doodle import dual_canvas
from IPython.display import display

# create a triangle diagram
swatch = dual_canvas.swatch(pixels=200)
points = [[-1,-1], [0,1], [1, -1]]
triangle = swatch.polygon(points, color="red", name="triangle")
swatch.fit(margin=10)
```

And here is the code which creates the slider and attaches the change callback.

```
# make a slider that changes the height of the triangle
slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=1.0, min=-1.0, max=1.0, step=0.1)
def onchange(*ignored):
    points[1][1] = slider.value  # set the tip height
    triangle.change(points=points)
slider.observe(onchange)
slider
```

The diagram is created using the jp_doodle package available here:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle

Read more about "observe" callbacks here:

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

Hope that helps!